# A formally weaker form of the extendable local reflexivity for Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces

Rosenthal introduce the notion of the extendable local reflexivity for Banach spaces as follows: Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $\lambda\geq 1$.  $X$ is said to be $\lambda$-extendably locally reflexive
($\lambda$-ELR) if for every finite-dimensional subspaces $E \subset X^{**}$
and $F \subset X^{*}$, and for every $\varepsilon > 0$,
there exists a bounded linear operator $T:X^{**}\rightarrow X^{**}$ with
$\|T\|\leq \lambda+\varepsilon$ such that
$T(E)\subset X$ and
$(Tx^{**})(x^*)=x^{**}(x^*)$ for every $x^{**} \in E$ and  $x^* \in F$. 
A Banach space $X$ is said to be ELR if $X$ is $\lambda$-ELR for some 
$\lambda \geq 1$. Rosenthal, Johnson and Oikhberg proved that a Banach space $X$ has the BAP and is ELR if and only if
$X^{*}$ has the BAP. Now if we replace the "$(Tx^{**})(x^*)=x^{**}(x^*)(x^{**} \in E, x^* \in F)$" in the definition by "$|(Tx^{**})(x^*)-x^{**}(x^*)| \leq
\varepsilon \|x^{**}\|\|x^*\|(x^{**} \in E, x^* \in F)$", we have a formally weaker form of the ELR. Moreover, we can prove that this formally weaker form of the ELR also permits to lift the BAP from a Banach space to its dual space. My question is: Is this formally weaker form of the ELR equivalent to the ELR? The answer,at least, is yes whenever the Banach space $X$ has the BAP.

Comment: @BillJohnson. I am sorry that I do not reply you as soon as possible because I am too busy to log in Mathoverflow when I come back to China. I do not know how to accept your answer to keep this thread from coming to the front. Could you tell me how to do?

Comment: Each answer has a checkmark, visible only to the OP,  below it. Click the checkmark to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes by a small perturbation argument.  For a small $\epsilon$, enlarge $F$  so that   $F$ $1+\epsilon$-norms $E$.  Get $T$ from the condition.    Choose any Auerbach basis $u_k$ for $E$ and take biorthogonal functions $x_k^*$ to $u_k$ with $x_k^*$ in $F$.  So $\|u_k\|=1$ and by the norming condition you can have $\|x_k^*\| \le 1 + \epsilon$. There are $x_k$ in $X$ biorthogonal to $x_k^*$ with $\|x_k\| \le (1 +\epsilon)^2$ (for example, by usual local reflexivity, or just by Helly's theorem). Define $S:X^{**} \to X$ by 
$$
Sx^{**} = \sum_k \langle x^{**},x_k^*\rangle  (1-\langle x_k^*, Tu_k \rangle ) x_k.
$$

Then $S$ has small norm if $\epsilon$ times the dimension of $E$ is small. Replace $T$ with $T+S$.

EDIT, 7/20/14. I wrote down the wrong expression for $S$. Rather than giving the most natural correct $S$, I'll explain in a more conceptual manner how to get $S$.  Having gotten $u_k$, $x_k^*$, and $x_k$ as above, you define $S$ on the span of $u_k$ so that for each $k$,

$$
Su_k = (1-\langle x_k^*, Tu_k \rangle ) x_k - \sum_{j\not= k} \langle x_j^*, Tu_k \rangle x_j
$$

so that for all $k$ and $j$ you have $\langle (T+S)u_k, x_j^* \rangle = \langle u_k, x_j^* \rangle$. The coefficients of each $x_j$ in the expression for $S$ are of order $\epsilon$, so, since $u_k$ is Auerbach and $x_k$ is almost Auerbach, The norm of $S$ on $E$ is of order at most $\epsilon N$, where $N$ is the dimension of $E$.  So $S$ can be extended to an operator from $X^{**}$ to $SE$ having norm of order at most $\epsilon  N^{1/2}$.

Comment: I am not sure that the operator $T+S$ satisfies $<(T+S)x^{**},x^{*}>=<x^{**},x^{*}>(x^{**}\in E, x^{*}\in F)$ and the norm of $x^{*}_{k}$ is less than and equal to 1+ϵ .

Comment: The norm condition on $x_k^*$ follows from the fact that $F$ almost norms $E$, which means that the natural mapping from $F$ to $E^*$ is almost (i.e., up to $1+\epsilon$) a quotient map.

Comment: I gave an incorrect formula for $S$ and so have made an edit to my answer.

Comment: The equality $<(T+S)u_{k},x^{*}_{j}>=<u_{k},x^{*}_{j}>$ only implies that $<(T+S)x^{**},x^{*}>=<x^{**},x^{*}>(x^{**}\in E, x^{*}\in span\{x^{*}_{k}:k=1,2,...n\})$. Is $(x^{*}_{k})_{k=1}^{n}$ a basis for $F$ ?

Comment: You are right.  I was trying to do it so that you can get estimates depending on the dimension of $E$.  Forget that and just enlarge $F$ and $E$ so that each is total over the other and choose $u_k$ Auerbach for $E$ and the unique biorthogonal $x_k^*$ in $F$, which must span $F$.  Now you have no good estimate on the norms of the $x_k^*$.  That does not matter because $\epsilon $ can be chosen small enough to compensate.

Comment: If $Z$ is a subspace of $X^{*}$ and $\{e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}$ is a basic sequence in $X^{**}$ such that $Z$ is total over $span\{e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}$, then is there a sequence $\{f_{n+1},...,f_{m}\}$ in $Z$ such that  $\{f_{n+1},...,f_{m}\}$ are biorthogonal to $\{e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}$? I am not sure of that.

Comment: I am not sure of your proof yesterday that we can enlarge $F$ and $E$ such that each is total over the other. Let $Z$ and $\{e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}$ be as your proof yesterday. Is there a sequence $\{f_{n+1},...,f_{m}\}$ in $Z$ such that $\{e_{n+1},...,e_{m}\}$ and $\{f_{n+1},...,f_{m}\}$ are biorthogonal?

Comment: You are right. Sorry!